# Flutter-Folio: Building Windows application... Exception: Build process failed. error G69E91ED9, error MSB8066

Tags: windows, flutter, exception, build

##### I cloned the repo and Installed Visual Studio and all the necessary tools as stated on the flutter website for windows applications. I have been using flutter for a while now so I have Visual Studio Code installed and configured for flutter. But when I run "flutter run -d windows" I get the error which says:

/D:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/visibility_detector-0.2.0/lib/src/visibility_detector_layer.dart(276,21): error G69E91ED9: Too many positional arguments: 1 allowed, but 2 found. [C:\Users\GTL-DAN-002\Documents\Projects\Flutter\flutter-folio\build\windows\flutter\flutter_assemble.vcxproj]
D:\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(242,5): error MSB8066: Custom build for 'C:\Users\GTL-DAN-002\Documents\Projects\Flutter\flutter-folio\build\windows\CMakeFiles\3350ef37c8b8b08ac8c1be72abc20593\flutter_windows.dll.rule;C:\Users\GTL-DAN-002\Documents\Projects\Flutter\flutter-folio\build\windows\CMakeFiles\c9ea6ec0dd188632dc4dfb02305c9fe9\flutter_assemble.rule' exited with code 1. [C:\Users\GTL-DAN-002\Documents\Projects\Flutter\flutter-folio\build\windows\flutter\flutter_assemble.vcxproj]

##### Below is the output of flutter doctor -v

flutter doctor -v
[√] Flutter (Channel dev, 2.9.0-0.1.pre, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22000.376], locale en-US)
• Flutter version 2.9.0-0.1.pre at D:\src\flutter
• Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
• Framework revision 8f1f9c10f0 (3 weeks ago), 2021-12-14 13:41:48 -0800
• Engine revision 234aca678a
• Dart version 2.16.0 (build 2.16.0-80.1.beta)
• DevTools version 2.9.1

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 31.0.0)
• Android SDK at C:\Users\GTL-DAN-002\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
• Platform android-31, build-tools 31.0.0
• Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.10+0-b96-7249189)
• All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Chrome - develop for the web
• Chrome at C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe

[√] Visual Studio - develop for Windows (Visual Studio Community 2022 17.0.4)
• Visual Studio at D:\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community
• Visual Studio Community 2022 version 17.0.32014.148
• Windows 10 SDK version 10.0.19041.0

[√] Android Studio (version 2020.3)
• Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
• Flutter plugin can be installed from:
https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
• Dart plugin can be installed from:
https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.10+0-b96-7249189)

[√] VS Code (version 1.63.2)
• VS Code at C:\Users\GTL-DAN-002\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
• Flutter extension version 3.32.0

[√] Connected device (3 available)
• Windows (desktop) • windows • windows-x64    • Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22000.376]
• Chrome (web)      • chrome  • web-javascript • Google Chrome 96.0.4664.110
• Edge (web)        • edge    • web-javascript • Microsoft Edge 96.0.1054.62
! Device 04669259A7007526 is not authorized.
You might need to check your device for an authorization dialog.

• No issues found!

Comment: Once try to run flutter run -d chrome if this is your flutter website